# TDDS Database references Old Server

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

We are deploying a new BizTalk 2016 infrastructure. After the installation and configuration, we had to move the databases to other DBServer.

Now is working, but sometimes we see this error on Event Log referencing to the old DB SERVER (**OLD_DBSERVER**):

> Either another TDDS is processing the same data or there is an
>   orphaned session in SQL server holding TDDS lock.A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server) SQLServer: **OLD_DBSERVER**,
>   Database: BizTalkMsgBoxDb.

We are looking for where is this configured, but we see in the registry and in the BizTalk databases **NEW_DBSERVER** and we can't find this setting. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Link broken - Managed to get the answer from the cache

```
SELECT [DestinationID]

      ,[DestinationName]

      ,[ConnectionString]

  FROM [BizTalkMgmtDb].[dbo].[TDDS_Destinations]

 

SELECT [SourceID]

      ,[DestinationID]

      ,[SourceName]

      ,[ConnectionString]

      ,[StreamType]

      ,[AcceptableLatency]

      ,[Enabled]

  FROM [BizTalkMgmtDb].[dbo].[TDDS_Sources]
```